# Ionic 3 grind with item sliding

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic3

I'd like to know how to use sliding items on a grid. I tried to use the sliding item, it even works with the `sliding`, plus it does not respect the columns anymore; it gets all mixed up.

Without the sliding item:

[image: without the sliding item]

With the sliding item:

[image: with the sliding item]

```
 <ion-item>
            <ion-grid>
    <ion-row  no-padding style="border: 1px solid grey;margin-left: 5px;margin-right: 5px;">
        <ion-col  col col-3 style="background-color: #ebf0f4;font-size: 8px;">
            USERNAME
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col   col col-3 style="background-color: #ebf0f4;font-size: 8px;">
            E-MAIL
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col  col col-3 style="background-color: #ebf0f4;font-size: 8px;">
            REGISTER AT
        </ion-col>
        <ion-col  col col-3 style="background-color: #ebf0f4;font-size: 8px;">
            SIDE
        </ion-col>

    </ion-row>
        <ion-row  *ngFor="let dado of data" no-padding style="border: 1px solid grey;margin-left: 5px;margin-right: 5px;">
            <ion-col col col-3    style="background-color: #ebf0f4;font-size: 8px;">
                {{dado.username}}
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col col col-3    style="background-color: #ebf0f4;font-size: 8px;">
                testeemail@teste.comsdaasdasdsaddsadasdd
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col  col col-3  style="background-color: #ebf0f4;font-size: 8px;">
                {{dado.created_at}}
            </ion-col>
            <ion-col  col col-3  style="background-color: #ebf0f4;font-size: 8px;">
                <div   *ngIf="dado.side_network == null ">
                    centter
                </div>
            </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
    </ion-grid>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what your actual **question** is. You're asking how to implement a sliding element in Ionic? Have you read the documentation?

Comment: yes buddy, it works right, but the columns do not work right they get `` shuffled'`

Comment: pls look the images